# Consumir Api de BBVA

Tags: api, postman

Estoy intentando consumir la Api de BBVA, pero me marca error.

Espero que me puedan apoyar a dar ideas de como solucionarlo.

> Documentación BBVA.

https://www.bbvaapimarket.com/es/api-developers/llamadas-a-una-api-mx/

> APP id

```
app.mx.ge2022
```

> Secret ID

```
#d$xhuETSvYW0uOI$qNH4PAWox5#d0#MuHM8p&nqZFjHfqO&HEcjC$yqE2KEc8Ed
```

> Credencial base64

```
YXBwLm14LmdlMjAyMjogI2QkeGh1RVRTdllXMHVPSSRxTkg0UEFXb3g1I2QwI011SE04cCZucVpGakhmcU8mSEVjakMkeXFFMktFYzhFZA==
```

> Mi petición por postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Variable {{credentials}}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta variable la cree para llamarla en el Header de tipo Autorization y en valor Basic {{credentials}}

> Error

```
    {
        "result": {
            "code": 401,
            "info": "Invalid credentials",
            "internal_code": "invalid_credentials"
        }
    }
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos.

Comment: Esas credenciales no tienen formato de Base64.

Comment: lo que hice fue lo siguiente
app.mx.ge2022: #d$xhuETSvYW0uOI$qNH4PAWox5#d0#MuHM8p&nqZFjHfqO&HEcjC$yqE2KEc8Ed

Eso lo converti a base64

Comment: Es lo que marca la documentación, pero no me da el token

Comment: Intente con este código en base64 YXBwLm14LmdlMjAyMjogI2QkeGh1RVRTdllXMHVPSSRxTkg0UEFXb3g1I2QwI011SE04cCZucVpGakhmcU8mSEVjakMkeXFFMktFYzhFZA==

Comment: pero tampoco me da acceso

Comment: Tres cosas que deberían estar claras tras 1752 puntos de rep: 1) No hay que crear otra pregunta; editar la que había y añadir lo que faltaba bastaba. De hecho, perdiste atención de los que ya la habíamos visto. 2) No hay que añadir datos sensibles reales. Publicar acá credenciales reales es hacer que estén disponibles en una simple búsqueda. 3) Cómo generas el base64 de las credenciales? **por favor indícalo yendo a [edit] la pregunta**. Los datos de la pregunta NO VAN en los comentarios

Comment: `Para obtener el valor del campo CREDENCIALES debemos convertir a base64 (www.base64encode.org) la concatenación de appID, “:” y Secret OAuth, es decir: appID:Secret OAuth.` Este escenario depende únicamente de ti, no podemos reproducirlo porque necesitamos tus credenciales, y eso de por sí ya es una brecha de seguridad crítica. Intenta leer la documentación detenidamente, a veces hay espacios en blanco que juegan en contra. Saludos.

Comment: Así fue como lo hice, colocando espacio y sin espacio desdpues de ":" pero me sigue mandando que las credenciales son invalidas

Comment: Cómo estás incluyendo ese Base64 EN la petición de postman? No es evidente. De nuevo, responde editando la pregunta. Los comentarios no son un chat

Comment: Cree una variable credentials

Comment: Esas credenciales son reales?

Comment: Si son reales y las coloque porque quiero que validen que les salga el mismo error que a mi. Enseguida que quede elimino la app y vuelvo a crear otra.

Comment: De hecho, probando con esos datos y usando correctamente la pestaña Authorization (para que postman haga el trabajo de añadir bien los datos), también falla. Suena a que ese no es el secret OAuth de tu app

Comment: Tal y como publicar tus credenciales puede ayudar a los demás a ayudarte, también estás regalando acceso a totales desconocidos que podrían usar tus credenciales con malas intenciones. Mi recomendación es que evites a toda costa publicar datos sensibles. Editar la pregunta para quitarlos no sirve (hay historial de ediciones). Si podés regenerar tus credenciales, esa sería la solución adecuada para esta brecha de seguridad.